# Removal of labels in Prometheus

Tags: monitoring, prometheus

I'm looking into our company using Prometheus to gather stats from our experiments which run on Kubernetes. There's a plan to use labels to mark the name of specific experiments in our cloud / cluster. This means we will generate a lot of labels which will hog storage over time. When the associated time series have expired, will the labels also be deleted?

Comment: Each unique set of labels is a time series. Be careful as labels with high cardinality can lead to a large increase in disk space usage.

Comment: Thanks @ConorB - is that a 'yes' to the question?

Comment: Let me expand on the question as I'm keen to have this answered. We will submit an experiment to our cluster, which consists of a number of jobs which will run on whatever nodes are available at the time. The experiment ID will describe the overall submission, but we would like short-lived labels to refer to each of the jobs. When the experiment time series expires, we'd like the job IDs (labels) to as well so they can be re-used, and avoid problems with high cardinality. The question is: when an experiment time series expires, do the labels also expire?

Answer (score 2):

`tldr;` From an operational perspective, Prometheus does not differentiate between time-series names and labels; by deleting your experiment data you will effectively recover the labels you created.

**What follows is only relevant to Prometheus >= 2.0**

Prometheus stores a times series for each unique combination of metric name, label, and label value. So `my_metric{my_tag="a"}`,  `my_metric{my_tag="b"}`, and `your_metric{}` are all just different time series; there is nothing special about labels or label values vs. metrics names.

Furthermore, Prometheus stores data in [2-hour frames on disk](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/storage/#on-disk-layout). So any labels you've created do not effect operations of your database after two hours, except for on-disk storage size, and query performance if you actually access that older data. Both of these concerns are addressed after your data is purged. Experiment away!